# FCM iOS project not receiving Notification - FCM console shows success but device does not receive

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

[image]1. Created a project in FCM console to send notifications.
2. The project has an Android app that does receive the notification
3. Next, I added the iOS App into that project. I uploaded the certificate p12 file, and made a notification

The FCM console shows that the notification was sent successfully, but it is not received on the real device.

Push Notification enabled in App IS.
Checked it in Capabilities
New cer file created from App - Created the Development cer file, Downloaded and double click and added into Keychain access. In that Private key exported and created the p12 file.
created the Provision profile and download and double click and add into xcode.
App run from xCode and got the FCM Token - Using the Token I send Notification and also send notification based on the App. But still i didn't receive any notification.
But in my Notification Page it shows success.

any idea to get to fix this issue.
am using xCode 9.2 and App in Swift 4 language.

Comment: you have certificate issue. Can you show me how are you getting P12 file from Keychain and how you making it?

Comment: Did you registered for remote notification and added the `GoogleService-Info.plist` file downloaded from Firebase ?

Comment: When you generate the token client-side, try sending from the console to this token as instructed in the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/first-message#send_a_notification_message) I've found that helps surface issues. That's how I found out that my App ID Prefix was written incorrectly.

Comment: @RatulSharker yes I have registered for remote notification. and added 
 'GoogleService-Info.plist'

Comment: @VeerSuthar  I have download  p12 from export the private key of *Apple Development Push services:MyappID* from keychain

Comment: Does it contain keychain/private key, 

If you highlight by screenshots, it will be great to find issue and fix it.

Comment: I've seen that, FCM token is generated even before the `device` token is acquired from device. First Make sure you can send push via device token using https://github.com/noodlewerk/NWPusher.git

Comment: @VeerSuthar I have added the Keychain access screen shot.. 

I have export the private key alone and upload that p12 file in firebase console 

I get error message *The certificate's bundleId did not match that of your app*
If i export iOSPushServices with Private key it accept the p12  file

Comment: Did you init firebase in AppDelegate, & plist file of Google downloaded from Firebase?

Comment: @VeerSuthar I can't get you clear.. *' init firebase in AppDelegate, & plist'*   . FCM message in not receiving when the app is open or in close.

at the time of app become active only console i receive the notification in console...

Comment: OKAY, it means, you are receiving msgs, but not showing pop up. got it.

Comment: @Rajendran , make changes in shown in answer.

Comment: @VeerSuthar Ok Sure.. *you are receiving msgs, but not showing pop up. got it*      
For this what should i do in code..

Comment: @Rajendran see my answer, try it.

Answer (score -1):

Do something like this, in AppDelegate, out of its body. as its extension.

```
extension AppDelegate : MessagingDelegate {
    func application(received remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage) {
        print("remoteMessage: MessagingRemoteMessage")
    }
}


extension AppDelegate : UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate {
    // MARK: - UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                                willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                                withCompletionHandler completionHandler:
        @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
        // Always show the incoming notification, even if the app is in foreground
        print("Received notification in foreground:")
        //let jsonString = notification.request.content.userInfo.jsonString ?? "{}"
        //print("\(jsonString)")
        completionHandler([.alert, .badge, .sound])
    }

    @available(iOS 10.0, *)
    func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
        print("Received notification response")
        //let jsonString = response.notification.request.content.userInfo.jsonString ?? "{}"
        //print("\(jsonString)")
        userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo
        NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
        completionHandler()
    }
}
```

Inside AppDelegate

```
 // MARK: - Push Notification Code
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],
                     fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
        // If you are receiving a notification message while your app is in the background,
        // this callback will not be fired till the user taps on the notification launching the application.
        // TODO: Handle data of notification

        // With swizzling disabled you must let Messaging know about the message, for Analytics
        // Messaging.messaging().appDidReceiveMessage(userInfo)

        print(userInfo)

        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {
            if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background {
                NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
            }
            else if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive {
                NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
            }
            else if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {
                    NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
            }
        }

        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
    }

    // MARK: -  Delegates Method For Push Notifications
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any]) {
        if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background || application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {
            //opened from a push notification when the app was on background

            if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.background {
                NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
            }
            else if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.inactive {
                NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
            }else if application.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active {
                if self.isAlreadyInConsult == false {
                    NotificationsService.shared.didReceiveNotificationFromBackground(userinfo: userInfo)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Also add in your project **plist**.

```
FirebaseAppDelegateProxyEnabled = NO
```